# Projection of 3D Exclusion Lines to 2D

Tags: plotting

I have a bunch of polynomials, which I draw them using this script

```
Plot3D[Min[3 x + 2 y, 2 y + 2 x + 1, y + 2 x, 2 y + 1, 1 ], {x, -3, 
  3}, {y, -3, 3}, Mesh -> Full, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["x"], Style["y"], Style["v"]}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Black]
```

I would like to project the 3D black lines to a 2D xy plane and keep those lines. How can I do this generically without using the `ContourPlot`?

Comment: With `ExclusionsStyle -> Black` what appear as _black lines_ are actually many small polygons covering _"interiors of excluded subregions"_.

Comment: Try `Plot3D[Min[3  x + 2  y, 2  y + 2  x + 1, y + 2  x, 2  y + 1, 
  1], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> None, AxesLabel -> {Style["x"], Style["y"], Style["v"]},
  ExclusionsStyle -> 
  Directive[EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[1/2], Green}], FaceForm[Red]]]`  and

Comment: `Plot3D[Min[3  x + 2  y, 2  y + 2  x + 1, y + 2  x, 2  y + 1, 
  1], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> None, AxesLabel -> {Style["x"], Style["y"], Style["v"]},
  ExclusionsStyle -> {FaceForm[], Directive[Thin, Cyan]}]` to see how excluded regions are rendered for `ExclusionsStyle -> styleregion` and `ExclusionsStyle -> {styleregion, styleboundary}`

Comment: @kglr, you are indeed correct, and this was the reason for having many small polygons when using `Contourplots.` If you could put these two helpful comments into an answer with a 2d projection, I can accept it so that this question is set as solved.

Comment: Shasa, posted an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ExclusionsStyle >> Details](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExclusionsStyle.html)

[image]

So... with `ExclusionsStyle -> Black` what appear as black lines are actually many small polygons covering "interiors of excluded subregions".

To see how excluded regions are rendered with settings `ExclusionsStyle -> styleregion` and `ExclusionsStyle -> {styleregion, styleboundary}` in more detail, set `Mesh` and `PlotStyle` to `None` and use `PlotRange` to zoom in a smaller portion of the surface.

```
Plot3D[Min[3   x + 2   y, 2   y + 2   x + 1, y + 2   x, 2   y + 1, 1],
 {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 PlotRange -> {{0, .75}, {-.5, .5}}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotStyle -> None, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[{Thin, Green}], FaceForm[Red]]]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Min[3   x + 2   y, 2   y + 2   x + 1, y + 2   x, 2   y + 1, 1], 
 {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, .75}, {-.5, .5}}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotStyle -> None, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> {FaceForm[], Directive[Thin, Blue]}]
```

[image]

To get 2D lines separating various regions of the surface, one possible way is to use `RegionPlot` as follows:

```
functions = {3  x + 2  y, 2  y + 2  x + 1, y + 2  x, 2  y + 1, 1};
```

#### RegionPlot

```
fiveRegions = Map[# <= Min[functions] &] @ functions;

RegionPlot[fiveRegions, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Cyan}, 
 PlotLegends -> Range[5], 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], Black]]
```

[image]

To get just the lines use `PlotStyle -> None` and to get rid of the outer boundary use a negative number for `PlotRangePadding`:

```
RegionPlot[fiveRegions, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotStyle -> None,  
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Black], 
 PlotRangePadding -> -.05]
```

[image]

#### Plot3D + ConditionalExpression

```
conditionalExpressions = 
  Map[ConditionalExpression[#, # <= Min[functions]] &]@functions;

plot3d = Plot3D[conditionalExpressions, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  Mesh -> None, Exclusions -> None, BoundaryStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

Extract lines and remove the last columns of coordinates

```
Graphics[
 Cases[Normal[plot3d], Line[x_] :> Line[x[[All, ;; 2]]], All], 
 PlotRangePadding -> -.05]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Thank you very much for providing further information.

Answer (score 3):

- Do you mean this result?
- Since `z==Min[3 x + 2 y, 2 y + 2 x + 1, y + 2 x, 2 y + 1, 1 ]` equivalence to `z<=3x+2y+0,z<=2y+2x+1,...` etc, that is `{-3,-2,1}.{x,y,z}<=0, {-2,-2,1}.{x,y,z}<=1, ...`,we use `HalfSpace[{-3, -2, 1}, 0],HalfSpace[{-2, -2, 1}, 1],...` to express such regions etc. and found their intersection.

```
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[#, 
      PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, {-20, 
         2}}] & /@ {HalfSpace[{-3, -2, 1}, 0], 
     HalfSpace[{-2, -2, 1}, 1], HalfSpace[{-2, -1, 1}, 0], 
     HalfSpace[{0, -2, 1}, 1], HalfSpace[{0, 0, 1}, 1]} // 
   RegionIntersection;
Graphics[MeshPrimitives[reg, 1] /. {x_, y_, z_} :> {x, y}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) This is a very nice idea. Thanks for sharing that.

Answer (score 3):

```
Min[3 x + 2 y, 2 y + 2 x + 1, y + 2 x, 2 y + 1, 1] == #1 == #2 & @@@ 
  Subsets[{3 x + 2 y, 2 y + 2 x + 1, y + 2 x, 2 y + 1, 1}, {2}];
Reduce[Or @@ %, {x, y}]
Region[ImplicitRegion[%, {x, y}], Axes -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, BaseStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
 TicksStyle -> Black]
```

---

```
(x < 1/3 && (y == -x || y == 1 - 2 x)) ||
(x == 1/3 && (y <= -(1/3) || y == 1/3)) ||
(1/3 < x < 1/2 && (y == -1 + 2 x || y == 1 - 2 x)) ||
(x >= 1/2 && y == 0)
```

[image]

Definitions of the five lines/infinite half-lines:

```
Min[3 x + 2 y, 2 y + 2 x + 1, y + 2 x, 2 y + 1, 1] == #1 == #2 & @@@ 
  Subsets[{3 x + 2 y, 2 y + 2 x + 1, y + 2 x, 2 y + 1, 1}, {2}];
Reduce[#, {x, y}] & /@ % /. False -> Nothing // Column
```

---

```
x <= 1/3 && y == -x
x == 1/3 && y <= -(1/3)
1/3 <= x <= 1/2 && y == -1 + 2 x
x <= 1/2 && y == 1 - 2 x
x >= 1/2 && y == 0
```

Comment: (+1)Thank you for sharing this answer. It is insightful.